# Permutations with a String

Tags: combinatorics

How many permutations of the string “ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ” contain
the substrings “HAVE” and “FUN”? Substrings must appear exactly as written.
e.g., LCQOPGRKFUNTYDIWSHAVEZXMJB is a valid substring.

My initial thought on this problem is maybe we could say that each work is three and four letters long, and by doing $\frac{26!}{4!3!}$, but I am wrong. I was wondering if someone could explain the solution to me.

The solution is: $21!$

Comment: There are $21$ things to permute: HAVE, FUN, and $19$ individual letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that FUN and HAVE as a single letter in that order.
The different number of arrangements of B,C,D,G,I,J,K,L,M,O,P,Q,R,S,T,W,T,Y,Z,FUN,HAVE is $21!$